# Kernel USB Driver for android

Tags: android, android-ndk

In My application I want to connect usb keyboard with my android based phone.
so Is it possible to connect keyboard with mobile?
I have tried to connect keyboard with mobile but there is no response form mobile.
should I need to install any kernel base driver or any other driver?
or there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to create your own driver using the NDK.